# How to access class values located in Form2 from Form1? C#

Tags: c#, forms, class

I have a quick question. I created a class in the Form2 called "MyObject" which has two variables in it. On the push of a button, the variables in Form2 are changed. Now my question is how to retrieve  MyObject in Form1? Here is my sample code:

Form1

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2(this);

        f.ShowDialog();
        ??????? (how can I retrieve Myobject here?????) 
    }
```

Form2

```
public class MyObject
    {
        public int Value1 { get; set; }
        public int Value2 { get; set; }

    }
    public Form2(Form1 frm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        obj.Value1 = 102;
        obj.Value2 = 50;
    }
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Well, you now have 2 valid implementations.  I recommend making it a Property, and declaring the MyObject class somewhere else, that is NOT inside the Form2 class.  It can be in the same file, but try to make sure the class definitions are distinct.  Properties are easier to handle than GetMethods, but less useful for CrossPlatforming or remoting, methods are easier to access than properties via reflection.

Comment: I am using the solution by Nikhil Agrawal and it works properly.

Comment: why -1? I have no idea how to ask questions so everyone should like it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

Form1

```
 public Form1()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
 }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Form2 f = new Form2(this);

    f.ShowDialog();
    MyObject mo = f.GetMyObject;
 }
```

Form2

```
public Form2(Form1 frm1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public MyObject GetMyObject 
{ 
    get
    {
        return obj;
    } 
}

MyObject obj;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    obj = new MyObject();
    obj.Value1 = 102;
    obj.Value2 = 50;
}
```

MyObject

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: for this I get this error (error is in Form1): The type or namespace name 'MyObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Amir: You have to write MyObject Class in same cs file or some new cs file.

Comment: I put it in a new cs file and that error is gone but I get a new error in Form2 regarding GetMyObject: Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'WindowsFormsApplication3.MyObject' is less accessible than method  'WindowsFormsApplication3.Form2.GetMyObject()'

Comment: even though this code is working fine at my end, still i have made some changes. I have made GetMyObject as property instead of a function.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't define `MyObject` inside of `Form2`.  You should put it in it's own file.  You almost always want each class to have its own file.

You should also give `MyObject` a better name; something that's more descriptive of what it actually does/holds.

Finally, to actually pass the data one easy and effective way is to just create a property on `Form2`:

```
public MyObject PropertyName {get; private set;}
```

(Don't forget to rename the property to something better.)

You can then set it from within `Form2` by saying `ProperyName = new MyObject();`

You can then access that property from `Form1` (after your call to `ShowDialog`) by using `f.PropertyName`.

Comment: The problem is the class value in my original extended code has more than 30 variables in it and I want to bring all of them at once to Form 1.

Comment: @Amir Well, that is quite a lot, so it's possible there is some underlying issue there.  It might be that a number of those variables should actually be in a single collection, or that you should have one or more additional complex types to encapsulate those variables.  (Or some combination of those two.)  If you described what they were we may be able to help with that.